# TSQL table properties dialog shows 10x # of rows compared to SELECT COUNT(*)

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM XXX
150,000,000
```

Table properties dialog, storage tab:

```
Row Count: 1,600,000,000 rows
```

Is the row count returning deleted rows or something?

Comment: What is 150,000,000  ??

Comment: Which database are you using ?

Comment: 150,000,000 rows from COUNT(*).  SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Which database are you using ?

Answer (score 3):

Try updating the usage statistics for that table with `DBCC UPDATEUSAGE ... WITH COUNT_ROWS` and see if it solves the issue (link to MSDN article about DBCC UPDATEUSAGE [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188414%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)).